# Show that two orthogonal probability measures have the following representations using Vitali covering

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, solution-verification

**Problem:**

$\alpha$ and $\beta$ are two mutually orthogonal probability measures in the sense that for some Borel subset $E\subset[0,1]$, $\alpha(E)=0$ and $\beta(E)=1$. If $F(x)=\alpha\{[0,x]\}$ and $G(x)=\beta\{[0,x]\}$ for $0<x\leq 1$, show that for any $\varepsilon>0$, there is finite collection of disjoint intervals $\{[a_i,b_i]\}$ s.t. $$\sum_iF(b_i)-F(a_i)<\varepsilon\text{ and }\sum_iG(b_i)-G(a_i)>1-\varepsilon$$

**Attempt:**

I'm using the following version of Vitali covering:

Given a Vitali covering $\mathcal{U}$ of a set $A\subset[0,1]$ and given any $\varepsilon>0$, there is a finite collection of disjoint intervals $\{E_i\}_{i=1}^{N}$ from $\mathcal{U}$ s.t. $$\mu^*\left(A\Delta\bigcup_{i=1}^{N}E_i\right)<\varepsilon$$

By Caratheodory extension, if $\mu$ is also a measure on $\sigma(\mathcal{R})$, the sigma ring generated by the semiring, $\mu^*=\mu$ on $\sigma(\mathcal{R})$. (???)

Apply this version of Vitali covering lemma to $\mathcal{R}:\{(a,b]:0\leq a<b\leq 1\}$, the semiring, then $\sigma(\mathcal{R})$ is the Borel set. Then we consider $\mu=\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}$. By Vitali covering, there exists disjoint $\{(a_i,b_i]\}_{i=1}^{N}$ s.t.
$$\mu\left(A\Delta\bigcup_{i=1}^{N}(a_i,b_i]\right)<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$$
which gives
$$\alpha\left(A\Delta\bigcup_{i=1}^{N}(a_i,b_i]\right)<\varepsilon\text{ and }\beta\left(A\Delta\bigcup_{i=1}^{N}(a_i,b_i]\right)<\varepsilon$$
Hence
$$\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left[F(b_i)-F(a_i)\right]=\alpha\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{N}(a_i,b_i]\right)=\alpha\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{N}(a_i,b_i]\setminus A\right)+\alpha(A)<\varepsilon$$
and
$$\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left[G(b_i)-G(a_i)\right]=\beta\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{N}(a_i,b_i]\right)=\beta(A)-\alpha\left(A\setminus\bigcup_{i=1}^{N}(a_i,b_i]\right)>1-\varepsilon$$

**Question:**

However, I am not so sure how to extend the outer measure given in Vitali covering (which applies to Lebesgue outer measure) to the probability measure on $[0,1]$. Can I just apply Caratheodory extension like just I did, or is it wrong and are there any other ways to do that? Other methods without using Vitali covering are also welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an attempt at a solution:

Use the outer regularity of $\alpha$ to pick an open set $K \supset A$ such that $\alpha(K) < \alpha(A) + \epsilon/2 = \epsilon/2$. Since $K$ is open, there exists a countable collection of intervals $\{[a_i, b_i]\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ with $K = \cup_{i=1}^{\infty}[a_i, b_i]$ and therefore there exists a finite  sub-collection $\{[a_i, b_i]\}_{i=1}^{n}$ that covers $K$:

$$ K \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}[a_i, b_i].$$

Now we can choose $N \geq n$ sufficiently large so that

$$\alpha(K) < \alpha \left( \bigcup_{i=1}^{N}[a_i, b_i]  \right) = \sum_{i=1}^N F(b_i) - F(a_i) < \epsilon.$$

I don't *think* we even need Vitali covering here, but I could be wrong. Not quite sure how to reconcile the issue of the intervals being disjoint, which is where Vitali might come in.

Proving the inequality for $\beta$ involves a similar argument, perhaps using the inner regularity instead of $\beta$ instead of outer regularity.

Hope this helps a bit! I'm interested in discovering the answer as well, so will follow this.

Comment: Actually, there is an approximation theorem between Borel subsets in $\mathbb{R}$ and union of finite disjoint collections of intervals, so that the Lebesgue measure of their symmetric difference is small. Applying this should solve the problem. You are right, we do not need Vitali in this case.